# MySQL single query to populate alphabetical glossary

Tags: php, mysql

Experts, I'm creating a glossary that has each letter of the alphabet as a link at the top - users can select a particular letter to see results that start with that letter. For example:

```
[All] [A] [B] [C] [D] ... [X] [Y] [Z]
```

But I don't have results for every letter so I don't want those letters to be clickable. So if there are no results that start with "X" for example, I would display [X] without a hyperlink. Otherwise, users have to click on a letter to see if there are results or not, which could be annoying.

My question is: Is there a single mysql query that can tell me how many results for a particular column (say "Name") that start with each letter of the alphabet? I'm trying to avoid executing a query for each letter as I'm rendering the page...

I'm looking for a something like:

```
NameThatStartsWith   NumOfResults
        A                 23
        B                 11
        C                 32 
       etc...
        X                  0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(Name, 1) as NameThatStartsWith, COUNT(*) as NumOfResults
FROM your_table GROUP BY LEFT(Name, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code was giving me an error which I've found out was because you cannot use an alias as part of a GROUP BY. I have edited your reply to fix this.